# linux remove all files except hidden files and folders

Tags: linux, rm

I have a directory structure like:

```
/Folder1/file1
/file2
/file3
/.file4
```

I need to remove only `/file2` and `/file3`. I want to keep `/Folder1/file1` and `/.file4`.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 4):

If globbing is disabled `rm *` will work. You can check whether `dotglob` is disabled with the `shopt` command. If it is turned on use:

```
shopt -u dotglob
rm *
shopt -s dotglob
```

Answer (score 3):

```
find . -type f -name "[^.]*" -delete
```

(Do it without `-delete` first, to be sure you typed it right.)

Comment: This doesn't keep "/Folder1/file1" that OP said he wanted to keep.

Comment: this is very concise but it will remove a hidden folder /.hiddenfolder also . Any way to keep the hidden folder also?

Comment: @OneXer It will not delete ANY folders, because it only finds files with `-type f`.

Comment: @jordanm You're right.  I missed that.  Will fix.

Comment: Won't `rm *` work?  That does not delete hidden files.

Answer (score -1):

```
find . -type f -name file{2,3} -delete
```

*type -f* search only for files, ignoring directories

*file{2,3}* file2 and file3

or

*file{2..6}* means range (file2, file3, file4, file5 file6)

Unless you search for wildcard before the file name like "*file" this will not delete hidden files.

To run only in the current directory to do not delete /Folder1/file1

```
find . -maxdepth 0 -type f -name file{2,3} -delete
```

But to run simply in the current directory i prefer the old **rm**.

```
rm file*
```